# Auth middleware optional in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I have my controller `ExampleController`:

```php
class ExampleController extends Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:student')->only(['store', 'update', 'destroy']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(CheckUser::student()) {
            dd("Is student");
        }
        dd("Isn't student");
    }

    /**
     * Another method's not relevant.
     **/
}
```

I'm trying to add some logic if is student.
But have one problem, I just can access: `Auth::user()` if I set the middleware. But this specific method can be accessed without has logged in.

**My question**

Is possible to create a *not required* middleware for what if logged get user information?

*Note*: I'm using Laravel passport with multi auth.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to protect specific methods that are in your controller and leave out others in the same controller

You may try to protect your endpoint on the routes files (api.php or web.php) rather than on the Constructor

```
//protected routes
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::post('customer/picture/add', 'Mobile\AuthController@addProfilePicture');
    Route::post('customer/phone/update', 'Mobile\AuthController@updatePhoneNumber');
});

//unprotected routes
Route::get('customer/login', 'Mobile\AuthController@getLoginForm');
```